# flickering screen when in reverse with engine on

Tags: electrical

i fitted a reverse camera to my Mercedes ml 300 2009 when engine is off the screen is nice and clear but when i stat the car up the picture from camera keeps flickering,the positive for the camera is via reverse light any one knows how to rectify it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to wire in a relay to supply 12 volt power to the camera. Use the reverse light power wire to activate the relay.